# Close Navigation window when button is clicked (Mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have a navigation menu which is almost perfect.

On Mobile:
When I open the hamburger menu, it will take up 3/4 of the screen size. I am okay with that. When I click on one of the links in the navbar I am taken to the correct section but the Menu remains open.

I prefer having the menu close as soon I click on one of the links rather than me having to press the Hamburger to close the menu.

HTML:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#education">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#experience">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#testimonials">Skills</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add minimal working code

Comment: `$('.nav-item').on('click', function() { $('.navbar').trigger( 'hidden.bs.collapse' ); })` try this one.

Comment: @AkshayBande That didnt seem to work.  I added the class nav-item onto each link but still nothing. Can you check my site out and see from there?

Comment: Give me the link for site.

Comment: @AkshayBande its https://www.soyebpatel.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

you can add click listener on all of `<a>`'s and then close the bar in listener function 
best way to do this is to give same class to all of them and add listener to them with for loop
or you can use jquery so you wont need for loop

Comment: How would I do this using jquery?

Comment: ``$(".navbar-nav a").on("click" , function() {
// code to close nav bar
})``

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){

$('.navbar-toggle').click(); 

});
```

Use this code, it will call click event for `navbar-toggle` class when you will click on navigation bar items. Which will close the navigation bar as you wanted.

Comment: you should always include some description with your code.